# htaccess redirect using get parameters and remove same parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please help me need redirect `search.html?searchword=value&searchphrase=all` to `search.html?searchword=value`

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchword=(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} searchphrase= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search.html\?searchword=%1 [R=301,L]
```

but it do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)searchphrase= [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(searchword=[^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^search\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Changes are:

- Order of `RewriteCond` is important. Keep the condition with capture group as last one
- No need to repeat `searchword` again in target, just capture from `RewriteCond` and use it later as back-reference `%1`
- Instead of using `.*` use `[^&]*` to match only value till you get next `&` or end of string
- Match `search.html` in rule pattern to avoid matching anything else

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```bash
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(search\.html)\?(searchword=[^&]*)&searchphrase=all [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I think this assumes `searchword` will always come before `searchphrase`

Comment: @anubhava, Hi sir, but I thought that's what OP is trying to achieve?